# want a logic to refresh the web page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public CashAdvanceHo GetPINNumber()
        {

            //Gets table body to 'myTable' instance

            IWebElement myTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='dgCAinformationDetails']/tbody"));



            //Getting Number of rows in table

            IList<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>(myTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));

            foreach (var colElement in rows)

            {

                //Getting Number of cols in row table

                IList<IWebElement> cols = new List<IWebElement>(colElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));

                if (cols.Count > 0)
                {



                    //Iterating through each cell

                    foreach (var cellData in cols)

                    {

                        //getting each cell data
                        counterforPINNumber = counterforPINNumber + 1;
                        String data = String.Empty; //= cellData.Text;

                        // Console.WriteLine("Data matched" + data);
                        if (counterforPINNumber == 11)
                        {

                            do
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                                //wrapper.Click(lnkInformation);
                                wrapper.EnterText(txtCarrierId, Wrapper.CarrierID);
                                wrapper.Click(btnCheck);
                                wrapper.SelectOptionFromList(lstSelectVehicleNo, CardActivationHo.CardNumber + " - " + CardActivationHo.VehicleNumber);
                                wrapper.Click(lnkInformation);
                                data = cellData.Text;
                                PINNumber = data;
                            }
                            while (data == string.Empty);

                            Console.WriteLine("PIN Number is : " + PINNumber);
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            return this;
        }`public CashAdvanceHo GetPINNumber()
        {

            //Gets table body to 'myTable' instance

            IWebElement myTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='dgCAinformationDetails']/tbody"));



            //Getting Number of rows in table

            IList<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>(myTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));

            foreach (var colElement in rows)

            {

                //Getting Number of cols in row table

                IList<IWebElement> cols = new List<IWebElement>(colElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));

                if (cols.Count > 0)
                {



                    //Iterating through each cell

                    foreach (var cellData in cols)

                    {

                        //getting each cell data
                        counterforPINNumber = counterforPINNumber + 1;
                        String data = String.Empty; //= cellData.Text;

                        // Console.WriteLine("Data matched" + data);
                        if (counterforPINNumber == 11)
                        {

                            do
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                                //wrapper.Click(lnkInformation);
                                wrapper.EnterText(txtCarrierId, Wrapper.CarrierID);
                                wrapper.Click(btnCheck);
                                wrapper.SelectOptionFromList(lstSelectVehicleNo, CardActivationHo.CardNumber + " - " + CardActivationHo.VehicleNumber);
                                wrapper.Click(lnkInformation);
                                data = cellData.Text;
                                PINNumber = data;
                            }
                            while (data == string.Empty);

                            Console.WriteLine("PIN Number is : " + PINNumber);
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            return this;
        }
```

I have added the above code in one of the test method. The Logic is after entering the data the application generates a PIN number which needs to be used for the Next Test case but sometimes the application takes time to generate the PIN number. So need a logic where my application page gets refreshed till the PIN number is generated.

Comment: Don't try to fix through `refresh()` associated _Javascript_ and _Ajax calls_ may not fire. Fix the `click()` instead.

Comment: Couldn't understand the logic behind fixing the click instead of refresh().could you Please brief me in detail if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can call

`driver.navigate().refresh();`

periodically while the PIN is generated.

Comment: could you please tell me in which line of the above code i have to use "driver.navigate().refresh();"

Comment: If you want to refresh until the PIN is ready, I think you need to check your PIN, maybe in a loop (while !isPinReady) or something like this. Place my code in this loop. BUT: I strictly warn you using dependent test cases!!! It's very bad practise! If the first test case fails, every other case in the chain is not executed! In critical projects it can cause big problems for you! Better avoid it.